# Laravel Notification not passing data and getting error "must be an instance of App\\Notifications\\User"

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use Laravel Notification to send email but getting this error

```
{
    "message": "Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\\Notifications\\UserResetPasswordNotify::__construct() must be an instance of App\\Notifications\\User, instance of Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection given, called in /home/fy3bgmgte060/public_html/svs.com/app/Http/Controllers/Api/LoginController.php on line 143",
    "status_code": 500
}
```

My Controller function

```
public function resendOTPTest(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where(['mobile' => $request->mobile])->first();

    Notification::send($user, new UserResetPasswordNotify($user));   

    return response()->json(['message' => 'success','data' => 'OTP Sent', 'success' => true], 200);
}
```

my Notification file

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class UserResetPasswordNotify extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->from('info@test.com')
            // ->name('Entrance India')
            ->subject('New OTP from SVS ')
            ->markdown('mail.userResetPassword', compact('user'));
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

this id my User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Order;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
         'fname','lname', 'email','gender', 'password' 
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

while trying to use Laravel Notification to send email but getting above error

But same thing is working for User creation function but it is not working for reset Password function

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In your notification file add `use App\User;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 
use  App\User
 in Notification file.

Answer (score 1):

### Include `User` Class in your `Notification` Class

You are *Injecting* `User` Dependency as *Typehint* to the **Magic Method** `__Cunstructor` into your `Notification` Class.
You have to make sure `Class` is available there.
Simply use this in your `Notification` Class.

> `use App\User`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> $user->notify(new UserResetPasswordNotify($user))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).